# External interrupt. Get individual bits of a uint8_t value

Tags: c, stm32, stm32cubeide

I use STM32F401CCU6 at 42 MHz. Pin PB0 connected to external interrupt source at 50 kHz. Pin PB10 is I/O - changing state every falling event. In external interupt i use this function, but it's not work propertly, the output is constantly different values, why?

```
uint8_t dataSND[4] = {0xA0, 0xB0, 0xC0, 0xD0};//data
uint8_t mode = 0;

void sendIO_Data(uint8_t state)
{
    if (state == 0)
        GPIOB->BSRR = GPIO_BSRR_BR_10;//set low
        //HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_10, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    else
        GPIOB->BSRR = GPIO_BSRR_BS_10;//set high
        //HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_10, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}

void setIO_In()
{
    GPIOB->MODER &= ~(GPIO_MODER_MODE10);//I/O to input
}

void setIO_Out()
{
    GPIOB->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE10_0;//I/O to output
}

void sendDATA()//send bit 0-7 of "dataSND" values 0-3
{
    sendIO_Data((dataSND[byteAddress] >> bitCntr) & 1);

    if (byteAddress == 3 && bitCntr == 7)
    {
        byteAddress = 0;
        bitCntr = 0;
        mode = 0;
        setIO_In();
        return;
    }

    bitCntr++;
    if (bitCntr == 8)
    {
        bitCntr = 0;
        byteAddress++;
    }
}


void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
    if (GPIO_Pin == GPIO_PIN_0)
    {
        uint8_t clock_state = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_0); //GPIO_PIN_SET - rising, GPIO_PIN_RESET - falling
        uint8_t reset_state = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_1);
        if (reset_state == GPIO_PIN_SET)
        {
            setIO_Out();
            cntr = 0;
            mode = 1;
        }

        if (clock_state == GPIO_PIN_RESET && mode == 1)
        {
            sendDATA();
        }
    }
}
```

But if I convert "dataSND" values to binary all work fine. Why?

```
uint8_t dataSND[32] = {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1};

void sendDATA()
{
    sendIO_Data(dataSND[cntr]);

    if (cntr >= 32)//+1
    {
        cntr = 0;
        mode = 0;
        setIO_In();
    }
    cntr++;
}
```

Thanks everyone. I changed the code with your comments and everything works.
But I don't understand why it's need to set "bitCounter = 0;" in "HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback" if it is equal to 0?

```
volatile uint8_t byteAddress = 0;
volatile uint8_t bitCounter = 0;
volatile uint8_t dataSND[4] = {0xA0, 0xB0, 0xC0, 0xD0};//data
volatile uint8_t mode = 0;

void sendIO_Data(uint8_t state)
{
    if (state == 0)
        GPIOB->BSRR = GPIO_BSRR_BR_10;//set low
    else
        GPIOB->BSRR = GPIO_BSRR_BS_10;//set high
}

void setIO_In()
{
    GPIOB->MODER &= ~(GPIO_MODER_MODE10);
}

void setIO_Out()
{
    GPIOB->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE10_0;
}

void sendDATA()
{
    sendIO_Data((dataSND[byteAddress] >> bitCounter) & 1);

    bitCounter++;

    if (bitCounter > 7)
    {
        bitCounter = 0;
        byteAddress++;
    }

    if (byteAddress > 3)
    {
        byteAddress = 0;
        bitCounter = 0;
        mode = 0;
        setIO_In();
    }
}

void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
    if (GPIO_Pin == GPIO_PIN_0)
    {
        uint8_t clock_state = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_0); //GPIO_PIN_SET - rising, GPIO_PIN_RESET - falling
        uint8_t reset_state = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_1);

        if (reset_state == GPIO_PIN_SET)
        {
            setIO_Out();
            bitCounter = 0;
            mode = 1;
        }

        if (clock_state == GPIO_PIN_RESET && mode == 1)
        {
            sendDATA();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks suspicious  when you check byte ==3 && bitCntr==7, reset the variables and then increment bitCntr immediately afterwards.

Comment: The second `sendData()` looks having a chance to access an out-of-range element `dataSND[32]`.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Maybe you only initialized unused `cntr` and forgot to initialize `byteAddress` and `bitCntr`, which are actually used in the former code?

Comment: Is it correct to use `GPIO_MODER_MODE10` (without `_0`) for setting to input and to use `GPIO_MODER_MODE10_0` (with `_0`) for setting to output?

Comment: @tinman But it is not done here because the `return;` in the `byteAddress == 3 && bitCntr == 7` case will prevent the increment.

Comment: Sem, If `(cntr >= 32)` is true then the prior line `sendIO_Data(dataSND[cntr]);` is _undefined behavior_ **UB** as it attempts access outside `uint8_t dataSND[32]`.  What are you trying to do with these lines of code?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I changed the code with your comments and everything works.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you only initialized unused `cntr` and forget to initialize `byteAddress` and `bitCntr`, which are actually used.

My suggestion is not using `byteAddress` and `bitCntr` as the state and instead calculating the values from one variable `cntr`.

```
void sendDATA()//send bit 0-7 of "dataSND" values 0-3
{
    int byteAddress = cntr / 8;
    int bitCntr = cntr % 8;
    sendIO_Data((dataSND[byteAddress] >> bitCntr) & 1);

    cntr++; // increment *before* comparing with 32
    if (cntr >= 32)//+1
    {
        cntr = 0;
        mode = 0;
        setIO_In();
    }
}
```